# Is there a way to change the leading's background of a ListTile on Flutter?

Tags: listview, flutter, background

I'm making a list using CircleAvatar as leading. I wanted the background to be the same color as the avatar circle making a square.

[The item 2 of the list shows what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ViOK.png)

Is there a easy way to do that?

This is my code by the way:

```
child: new ListTile(
              leading: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                child: Text(listData[i].index,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
              ),
              title: new Text(listData[i].word),
              subtitle: new Text(listData[i].definition),
            onTap: (){
                print("Tocou!");
            },
          ),
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could remove ListTile's the content padding (16 horizontal) and use AspectRatio :

```
ListTile(
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
            leading: AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: 1,
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.red,
                child: Center(
                  child: Text("1",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            title: Text(listData[i].word),
            subtitle: Text(listData[i].definition),
          onTap: (){
              print("Tocou!");
          },
        ),
```

Comment: Do you have any idea how could I remove the padding at the top and at the bottom?